# cookie returns null every time i perform a refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, basic-authentication

i am currently developing an authentication functionality in Node.js (Express) which consists of login refresh and logout controller methods. I have no issues with the login functionality, as it create a jwt access token as expected.

```
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const User = require('../models/user.model.js');


const login = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body

  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
  }

  const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username }).exec()


  if (!foundUser) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' })
  }

  const match = await bcryptjs.compare(password, foundUser.password)

  if (!match) { return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorised' }) }


  const accessToken = jwt.sign(
    {
      "UserInfo": {
        "username": foundUser.username,
        "roles": foundUser.admin_roles
      }
    },
    process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET,
    { expiresIn: '15m' }
  )

  const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
    { "username": foundUser.username },
    process.env.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET,
    { expiresIn: '7d' }
  )

  // Create secure cookie with refresh token 
  res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  })

  console.log(res.cookie)
  // Send accessToken containing username and roles 
  res.json({ accessToken });
});
```

However, when i run the refresh method (all methods are tested through Thunder Client Api, which is similar to Postman) there's no cookie to be found, therefore it return a 204 error. the code works as it should however, checking with console log i realised that there isn't a request cookie at all for the refresh method to operate on.

```
const refresh = (req, res) => {
  const cookies = req.cookies

  console.log(cookies)

  if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'cookie nof found' })

  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt

  jwt.verify(
    refreshToken,
    process.env.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET,
    asyncHandler(async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' })

      const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: decoded.username }).exec()

      if (!foundUser) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' })

      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
          "UserInfo": {
            "username": foundUser.username,
            "roles": foundUser.admin_roles
          }
        },
        process.env.JWT_ACCESS_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '15m' }
      )

      res.json({ accessToken })
    })
  )
}
```

any ideas of why the cookie isn't past on?
[image]

I tried to check if the cookie wasn't created in the login method, but it it.still don't understand why it isn't passed on